# Migrating stories from Drupal 5 to Drupal 6

Tags: 6, nodes, migrations

I am designing a Drupal 6 website from scratch, but I need to import about 5,000 story type nodes from a Drupal 5 website into the new one. What might be some of the ways to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally follow the steps described below:

1) Transfer my Drupal 5 site in a test machine (possibly a local VMWare Development Machine).

2) Convert the Drupal 5 site to Drupal 6 using the guide that you can find [here](http://drupal.org/node/340073).

3) Use a Node Export/Import module to transfer the nodes from the local site to the new/from-scratch-built website. (e.g. [Node Export module](http://drupal.org/project/node_export))

Note: If you do not know how to transfer your live site to your local machine the steps that I usually follow are:

a) Download the live site's files locally

b) Export the live database through PHPmyAdmin and save it locally

c) Import the database in my local MySQL server

d) Most of the times the links don't work properly in the local machine. The most common reason for this is that the local server does not have the capability for clean URLs so I add this to the httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/yourDirName>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /yourDirName
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

and restart the apache server (notice that you will have to replace the "yourDirName" part with whatever your dir name actually is)

Comment: Thank you! That's actually what I did except for the httpd.conf bit... so I guess I'll just go make that change in MAMP then. Thanks, will let you know if it works!

Comment: Keep in mind that since you are working in Mac you will need to change the directory accordingly (I assumed that you were working on Linux locally thus I used the default http dir of Apache in ubuntu, i.e. /var/www).

Comment: OK great! I will change it to /sites/ then.

Comment: Instead of copying those directives, which are already used in the .htaccess file that comes with Drupal, it would be better to change the directive AllowOverride for the server root folder to `AllowOverride All`. I have a test site on my Mac, and clean paths are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [Table Wizard module](http://drupal.org/project/tw), which can assist with node imports from other systems (drupal sites or otherwise).

Comment: It says it is deprecated. Take a look at the [Data-Module](http://drupal.org/project/data) instead.

Comment: Yeah I saw that... but the data module is only available in alpha release... safe enough to use?